# Is it possible to convert this to array/dictionary to make it faster

Tags: vba, excel

I use this vba code to lookup a file with 100000+ rows and columns. is it possible to re-write this code as an array or use a scripting dictionary?

```
   Sub vlookuptest()
   Dim i As Long
   On Error Resume Next
   For i = 2 To 1048576
   Sheets("Prices").Cells(i, 6) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup((Worksheets("Prices").Cells(i, 4) & Worksheets("Prices").Cells(i, 3)), Worksheets("Raw Delta").Range("A:O"), 14)
   Next i
   End Sub
```

This is my trial code. Problem on this one is that it doesn't search perfectly.

```
  Option Explicit
  
  Sub DRT_GetValues()
  Dim supplierNumber As String
  supplierNumber = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main").Range("D5").Value
  Const COL_ARTNUM As Long = 1
  Const COL_ARTDESC As Long = 2
  Const COL_PRICECITY As Long = 9
  Const COL_PRICECOUNTRY As Long = 10
  Const COL_CURRENCY As Long = 11
  Const COL_NETPRICE As Long = 14
  
  Dim d As Variant, u As Long, r As Long, k, action, w As Long, x As Long, y As Long
  Dim dict As Object
  Dim dOut(), rOut As Long, i As Long
  Dim newRow As Boolean
  
  Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
  
  d = Sheets("Raw Delta").Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Offset(2, 0).Value
  u = UBound(d, 1) - 1
  
  i = 1
  ReDim dOut(1 To u, 1 To 14) 'to hold the output data
  
  
  'loop over the input data
  For r = 1 To u
  
  
  k = d(r, COL_ARTNUM) & d(r, COL_PRICECOUNTRY) & d(r, COL_PRICECITY) & "-" & supplierNumber
  
  If Not dict.exists(k) Then
  dOut(i, 6) = d(r, COL_NETPRICE)
  dict.Add k, i
  i = i + 1
  End If
  rOut = dict(k)
  
  Dim wow As String
  wow = Sheets("Prices").Cells(i, 4) & Sheets("Prices").Cells(i, 3)
  
  If wow = k Then
  
  dOut(rOut, 1) = d(r, COL_NETPRICE)
  
  End If
  
  Next r
     
     
  
  Sheets("Prices").Range("f2").Resize(u, 14).Value = dOut
  
  End Sub
```

Comment: Is the string resulting from the concatenation of columns D & C guaranteed to be unique? What are the chances it will be found in the 'Raw Data' worksheet's column A?

Comment: You're referencing columns A:O on the 'Raw Data' worksheet but asking for the result from column N (14th column). Is that correct?

Comment: Yes it is concatenation and unique.

Comment: It's just that its takes too long.

Comment: you wrote 100000+, but into your loop I see 1 milion and more, correct?!?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This builds a scripting dictionary object using the 'Raw Data' worksheet's column A as the **Key** and the price (...?) from column N as the **Item**.

On the 'Prices' worksheet, it grabs data from columns C & D. To lookup the prices from the dictionary, it concatenates these values and looks for a matching key.

Finally, it returns the found values back to column F of the 'Prices' *en masse*.

```
Sub vlookup_replacement()
    Dim v As Long, vRDA As Variant, vRDN As Variant, vPDC As Variant
    Dim dRDAN As Object

    'Debug.Print Timer
    Set dRDAN = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With Worksheets("Raw Data")
        vRDA = Intersect(.Columns("A:A"), .UsedRange).Value2
        vRDN = Intersect(.Columns("N:N"), .UsedRange).Value2
        For v = LBound(vRDA, 1) To UBound(vRDA, 1)
            If Not dRDAN.exists(vRDA(v, 1)) Then _
                dRDAN.Add Key:=vRDA(v, 1), Item:=vRDN(v, 1)
        Next v
    End With

    'Debug.Print dRDAN.Count & ":" & UBound(vRDN, 1)

    With Worksheets("Prices")
        With .Cells(2, 3).Resize(.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row - 1, 4)
            .Columns(4).ClearContents
            vPDC = Intersect(.Columns("A:B"), .Cells).Value2
            For v = LBound(vPDC, 1) To UBound(vPDC, 1)
                vPDC(v, 2) = vPDC(v, 2) & vPDC(v, 1)
                vPDC(v, 1) = dRDAN.Item(vPDC(v, 2))
            Next v
            .Cells(1, 4).Resize(UBound(vPDC, 1), 1) = vPDC
        End With
    End With

    'Debug.Print Timer

    dRDAN.RemoveAll: Set dRDAN = Nothing

End Sub
```

A large part of the improvement of working within large memory blocks is avoiding the looping through individual worksheet cells. Knowing the nature of the data, unique values in key columns and what the chances are of finding matches helps design the processes by avoiding unnecessary error control.

While this is certainly going to be faster than your [VLOOKUP functions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65), you can add some functionality to it.

Comment: This really worked! Thanks. I edited my question. I added the code I am working on. Can you check what's wrong and missing on my version of the code? using the same concept of what you did

Comment: It seems like you are only trying to find **wow** in a forward progression; not by looking at **dict** as a completed dictionary.

Comment: The logic of that is that "wow" is a container for the comparison of the key.

Comment: Hi Jeeped. I double checked everything and I'm missing some data eventhough it is present on the "Raw Delta" it is not showing on "Prices"

Comment: My own proofing was from 100K rows in 'Pricing' from 400K rows in 'Raw Data' (all randomly generated). I checked the first 1K rows of results and everything was spot-on. Unfortunately, I could not even start to guess at the mismatches you've experienced without a first-hand look at the data and given the scope of your data, that sounds like it is getting beyond what I offer here. *"it is present"* just isn't much to go on. If you think about it, it is almost assuredly a problem with the data. Things do not work for a thousand times and then just decide to go wrong.

Comment: I can send a copy of the data itself if its okay for you to check it out. I'm also trying to modify the code you sent and can't seem to see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I test this code and 120K record run in 00:00:11,

```
Sub vlookuptest()
Dim avvio As Date
Dim arresto As Date
Dim tempo As Date
avvio = Now
   Dim findArray(2 To 120000)  As Variant
   For i = 2 To UBound(findArray)
    findArray(i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup((Worksheets("Prices").Cells(i, 4) & Worksheets("Prices").Cells(i, 3)), Worksheets("Raw Delta").Range("A:O"), 14)
   Next i
   Sheets("Prices").Range("F2:F120000") = findArray
arresto = Now
tempo = arresto - avvio
MsgBox tempo

End Sub
```